# Qual è il significato dell'espressione "a cacchio"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Le certezze del dubbio* di Goliarda Sapienza ho letto:

> «E tu sei insopportabile con questi appuntamenti a cacchio che mi dai! Insomma, si può sapere qual è questa sorpresa che mi avevi annunciato? Spero che non sia lo scherzo - e ne saresti capace - di portarmi a bere un *whisky* pessimo in questo lurido bar!»

Ho cercato il vocabolo "cacchio" in alcuni dizionari, comunque non capisco cosa significhi "a cacchio" in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Come ha speigato **kos**, "cacchio" è generalmente utilizzato come sotituto meno volgare di "cazzo"  nelle esclamazioni, ad esempio "Non capisci un cacchio", "Ma che cacchio dici?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In questo contesto "a cacchio", come "a cavolo", è un'espressione utilizzata per sostituire la più famosa e sicuramente più volgare "a cazzo" (da notare il fatto che iniziino tutte con "ca", e curioso credo anche il fatto che questi riferimenti siano sempre rivolti al mondo vegetale); significa approssimativamente "fatto male", "fatto disorganizzatamente" o "fatto non bene". [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cacchio1/) non cita quest'accezione, comunque posso confermare che da me è usata molto comunemente. Citando [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacchio):

> La parola cacchio è un termine agricolo che indica propriamente i germogli della vite o di alcuni tipi di piante rampicanti o infestanti. Tuttavia la parola cacchio, come peraltro succede alla sua omologa più volgare, viene utilizzata in moltissimi contesti, spesso dialettali, assumendo significati anche molto diversi e per nulla scurrili.
>   [...] Per quanto riguarda invece l'uso in contesti differenti, sembra più opportuno pensare che si tratti di una forma sostitutiva, probabilmente dovuta al dialetto romanesco, della parola cazzo con un termine agricolo, sentito come meno volgare, piuttosto che una modifica di questa.

Comment: Condivido il merito della risposta, e ricordo a @kos che [non c'è bisogno di censurare nessun tipo di parola](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-to-handle-swear-words). Ovviamente qui non si *usa* il turpiloquio, ma se è utile *menzionarlo* si può fare benissimo (così come su un vocabolario).

Comment: @DaG Ho anche cercato una discussione del genere su meta ma non sono riuscito a trovare nulla, quindi ho censurato tutto tanto per stare tranquilli perché non sapevo quale fosse la policy qui. Grazie del link, condivido pienamente la scelta di non censurare niente.

Comment: Nella mia esperienza ho spesso sentito usare anche "a pera". Benché non inizi con "ca", anche questa espressione deriva dal mondo vegetale... (da notare, però, che il termine "cazzo" non ha a che fare con i vegetali)

Comment: @A.P. Forse può darsi che l'abbia sentito anch'io. Comunque no, indubbiamente il termine "cazzo" non ha niente a che fare con i vegetali; in ogni caso alla fine in qualche modo i vegetali c'entrano sempre, alcuni per ovvi motivi, altri per meno (vedi e.g. "banana" e "pisello"... per non parlare delle controparti femminili "pere" e "patata").